# Initializing an array agent attribute from a database

Tags: arrays, attributes, initialization, anylogic, agent

I'm generating agents where two attributes (Modules and Passed_Modules) are arrays. I would like to draw their values from a database reference in the same way as I'm able to do for the scalar attributes. There is no such option, however. How can I initialise these array attributes by drawing from a database?

Here is the option associated with one of the scalar attributes (i.e. HistoricYear):

[Scalar attribute has the option to initialise from a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU5cT.jpg)

However, there is no such option for the array attributes (e.g. Modules):

[Array attribute does not have this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YKQI.jpg)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to have a function that uses the database values and then returns an array for you to use.

[image]

and then the `getModules` function you have some code that goes through the DB for you and return an array:

```
int[] result = new int[10];

List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(module_table).list();

int i = 0;
for (Tuple row : rows) {
    result[i](row.get( module_table.modules ));
    i ++;
}


return result;
```