# Initializing an hyperarray parameter agent attribute from a database

Tags: arrays, database, parameters, anylogic

I am similar problem to this [Initializing an array agent attribute from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928785/initializing-an-array-agent-attribute-from-a-database/71929868#71929868) but Im having a problem as it brings back the whole row of data and not only one value.

```
for( int i=1; i < Modules.size()-1; i++) {

    List< Tuple > plan =
    selectFrom( Database ).list();
    
    
    for( int j=1; j < Modules.size()-1; j++) {
    
    Modules.set(i,Database.get(i,j));
    
    //}
}
```

I would like  to set Modules [i] == Database [1,j].

Does anyone have advise on how I can run through the different columns?

[Modules is a HyperArray Parameter](https://shoprite-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/sslamang_shoprite_co_za/ETZHFjHuyvpMp3JpQXUGJggBSfRU79yxvnICIXHK9leOTQ?e=Vk2qGH)

[Database](https://shoprite-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/sslamang_shoprite_co_za/EUtEzng08YBLhOweISe70MQBhS-shaCWcOUpJNKoJI8kIw?e=bwkI0h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something similar to this... use it as a guideline, but you will have to modify it a bit since i didn't test it.

```
Tuple t =selectFrom( Database ).list().get(0);//first row
       int i=1;
        Database.getColumns().forEach(col -> {
            String colName = col.getMetadata().getName(); 
            
            if (!colName.equals("al_id")) {
                double value=(double)t.get(col);
                Modules.set(value,i);
                i++;
                
            }
        });
```