# Get name of dimensional array

Tags: database, multidimensional-array, parameters, anylogic

I am currently trying to match a HyperArray parameter to the database.

I am trying to get the match the Dimension name to the database name. I am struggle to call/get the Dimension name. Does anyone have advise on how I could call the dimension name if I select Dimension 1.

[Modules is a HyperArray Parameter](https://shoprite-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/sslamang_shoprite_co_za/ETZHFjHuyvpMp3JpQXUGJggBSfRU79yxvnICIXHK9leOTQ?e=OKAwsI)

[Database](https://shoprite-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/sslamang_shoprite_co_za/EUtEzng08YBLhOweISe70MQBhS-shaCWcOUpJNKoJI8kIw?e=pKJMhY)

[Previous Assistance Received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047784/initializing-an-hyperarray-parameter-agent-attribute-from-a-database/72051280#72051280)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you know, a variable can have multiple dimensions, and each dimension can have multiple values, where each value is associated to a name.

There are 2 indexes of importance, the first one is the one associated to the index of the dimension, let's call it dimIndex
In your case there's only 1 dimension called Module_List so, dimIndex must be equal to 0

The second one is the value of that dimension, in your case Module_List has values of Busman_113 and Busman_124

`Modules.getDimensions()[dimIndex].getIndexName(0)` will be equal to "Busman_113"
and
`Modules.getDimensions()[dimIndex].getIndexName(1)` will be equal to "Busman_124"